# What compatibility trade-offs do we need to make in order to use a hardened SSL config for Nginx?

Tags: nginx, security, ssl

I found some hardened SSL settings in [github.com/ioerror/duraconf](https://github.com/ioerror/duraconf/blob/master/configs/nginx/nginx.conf).

Here is the header from the config:

> This is an example of a high security, somewhat compatible SSLv3 and TLSv1
>    enabled HTTPS proxy server. The server only allows modes that provide perfect
>    forward secrecy; no other modes are offered. Anonymous cipher modes are
>    disabled.  This configuation does not include the HSTS header to ensure that
>    users do not accidentally connect to an insecure HTTP service after their
>    first visit.

It only supports strong ciphers in PFS mode:

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;

# Only strong ciphers in PFS mode
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
```

If we were to use these settings on our website, what does "somewhat compatible" mean? For example, would IE6 still be able to connect?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, IMO. However, you should be pretty compatible with that, though I've never seen much need to change it from the default ciphers of `ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;` explained in the [Nginx Wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule). [Here's a good browser compatibility list for TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers). [Here's a compatibility list for Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2011/10/02/10218922.aspx).

Comment: @nojak You've never heard of BEAST? CRIME? Forward secrecy?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Apparently I need to look into those...

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer on Windows XP (that’s 6, 7 and 8) can’t connect because they don’t support Forward Secrecy. You can test things like this on your own over at [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

Other than that everything should work, but there might be old mobile clients that can’t connect as well. This would need further testing.

---

Personally I think this configuration isn’t suitable for real world websites. `AES256` is a sham and only increases the connection time. `AES128` is more than good enough for *normal* websites, have a look at [this document from Seagate](http://www.scribd.com/doc/29872766/128-Bit-vs-256-Bit-AES-Encryption). Unless you’re planning to deploy a banking website or maybe a whistle blower thingy go with `AES128` and spare your server from the computing overhead.

My personal configuration for nginx looks like the following (full nginx configuration can be found [in one of my repositories](https://github.com/MovLib/www/tree/master/conf/nginx)).

```
# Content Security Policy
#
# LINK: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/
add_header    X-WebKit-CSP              "default-src 'self' *.example.com;";
add_header    X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' *.example.com;";
add_header    Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' *.example.com;";

# Do not allow embeding of our website in iframes.
#
# LINK: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034
# LINK: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-websec-frame-options-00
add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
add_header Frame-Options   "DENY";

# Only communicate view encrypted connections on all domains, forever!
#
# LINK: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=262974383; includeSubdomains;";

# (Re)Enable web browser XSS filter protection (IE+Chrome).
#
# LINK: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-iv-the-xss-filter.aspx
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

# Use a public DNS to resolve OCSP responder hostnames. The answer stays valid for a complete day.
#
# LINK: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm
resolver 209.244.0.3 209.244.0.4 valid=86400;

# We only support AES128 and Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman (ECDH) plus Diffie–Hellman (DH) in order to enable Forward
# Secrecy. This configuration ensures highest compatibility, best performance while still being extremely secure. Please
# note that using AES128 isn't really less secure than any other AES implementation.
#
# LINK: http://www.scribd.com/doc/29872766/128-Bit-vs-256-Bit-AES-Encryption
ssl_ciphers    "EECDH+AESGCM EDH+AESGCM EECDH -RC4 EDH -CAMELLIA -SEED !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4 !AES256";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;

# Prefer our configured ciphers over the client specified ones.
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# Only support newest protocols, unfortunately we have to support TLS 1.0 and 1.1, otherwise 99% of the internet can't
# connect to our server.
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

# Use a shared (among all nginx worker threads) cache for SSL sessions; one megabyte can store about 4000 sessions.
#
# LINK: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m;

# Number of seconds before an SSL session expires in the session cache. Should match the keepalive value.
#
# LINK: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_timeout
# LINK: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncachetimeout
ssl_session_timeout 60;

# Enable OCSP stapling.
#
# LINK: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4366#section-3.6
# LINK: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6066
ssl_stapling        on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

# The certificate of our authority for OCSP verification.
ssl_trusted_certificate ssl/ca-bundle.pem;
```

I also use a custom `init.d` script to start nginx and directly fetch the OSCP response, this ensures that all clients can validate it. You can find it [in one of my repositories](https://github.com/MovLib/www/blob/master/bin/init-nginx.sh).

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by "hardened" in case of SSL?

which cipher_suites are used  in the first hand depends on what cipher_suites are available on your server, then on server_suggestions, then on what the client is able to speak. with those cipher_suites you have ECDHE and DHE configured which is kinda ok when you want to use PFS, but since only TLSv1 ist enabled, i dont think you can use ECDHE anyway, so you'll stick to DHE, which might be used with most browsers. Some very legacy clients (IIRC IE <= 9) might not be able to use PFS, so you'll keep them out with this config.

if you wan to browser-test out the given cipher_suites:

- configure your nginx to use them
- check those ciphers against [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)
- you can check which ciphers are available on your server with `openssl ciphers`

the problem with taking cipher_suggestions from 3rd parties:

- if you server cant speak tlsv1.2 you wont be able to use modern PFS-cipher-suites like all those ECDHE - ciphers, but will use the very slow DHE - ciphers
- you should perftest and ssllabs-check your cipher-suites always to see which browsers could get problems.

you might find more infos on nginx + ssl here: [Guide to Nginx + SSL + SPDY](http://www.mare-system.de/guide-to-nginx-ssl-spdy-hsts/)

---

some things i dont like about the nginx-config you linked to:

- the cache is also caching "hickups" from upstream
- the ssl-config is not really the best and surely NOT high security

~~~

```
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
# -> no tlsv1.2/tlsv1.2??? this is NOT high security
# as mentioned in the header

proxy_cache_valid  any 1h;
# REALLY???
```

~~~

Comment: ECDHE suites are allowed in SSLv3 and later. Suites that use SHA2 (SHA256 or SHA384) and suites that use GCM can't be used in TLSv1.1 and earlier

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that "somewhat compatible" is used as a way of saying "not fully compatible".

That cipher list does not support IE6 as IE6 has no FPS ciphers available to it.

You might also find [this article](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy) of use.